# How to connect WiFi printer to Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: wireless, printing

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04 LTS. I have an HP OfficeJet 6700 AIO connected to wifi router. The Printers setting in Ubuntu doesn't see the printer and I can't connect. I have tried using the IP address of the priinter, and the Printers app finds it, but when I click the FORWARD button, I get a dialog with 'CUPS Server Error - internal-server-error' message

Comment: You may want to try the guidance in [this document](http://people.ubuntu.com/~gunnarhj/printing-setup.html).

Comment: Does the router see the printer? Do you know its IP address?